# Porque no funciona mi preventDefault() en un href

Tags: javascript, html, rutas, preventdefault

quiero redirigir de una pagina a otra con un  pero con una alerta de confirmacion para poder saber si quiere ir a otra pagina, la cuestion es que no me agarra el preventDefault();

codigo html

```
<a href="../CARREAS/carreras.php" onclick="confirmacion()" > Ir a otra pagina </a>
```

codigo js

```
function confirmacion(e){
    if( confirm('¿Estas seguro que quieres ir a otra pagina?') ) {
        return true
    }else{
        e.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

ya revise la ruta de mi html a mi js y si esta bien, si aparece el mensaje pero no me previene la confirmacion, aunque le de a "cancelar" igual me lleva a la otra pagina

Comment: prueba con `onclick="confirmacion(e)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `confirmacion(e)` debe recibir el evento como argumento, el cual no estás definiendo, defínelo de esta forma al llamar `onclick`:

```
<a href="../CARREAS/carreras.php" onclick="confirmacion(event)"> Ir a otra página </a>
```

---

```js
function confirmacion(e){
    if( confirm('¿Estas seguro que quieres ir a otra pagina?') ) {
        return true
    }else{
        e.preventDefault()
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="../CARREAS/carreras.php" onclick="confirmacion(event)" > Ir a otra pagina </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

El tema esta en como se se esta usando la funcion confirmacion() en el atributo onclick, el parametro 'e' de la funcion confirmacion(e) representa el objeto del evento y tiene que ser pasado como argumento a la funcion onclick.

Proba esto

```
<a href="../CARREAS/carreras.php" onclick="confirmacion(e)" > Ir a otra pagina </a>
```

Ojala te sirva, saludos!